# Emoji Colour Google Play Store Application

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, emoji

I've just uploaded my first Kotlin project to the Google Play Store but the red emoji used from my mac is showing up black on some android devices. Does anyone know how to ensure the emoji used keeps its colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While emoji are standardised the actual appearance on a particular device is up to the manufacturer, so a smiling emoji  will look different on a Samsung phone than it does on an iPhone, or in your case different between your Mac and an Android phone.

This site shows all the differences 
http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

There is no way to stop this behaviour of different looking emoji so in your case, for the Google Play listing, I would suggest selecting any emoji you would like to use on an Android device so you see the same thing users will see (although bear in mind there will be differences between Google and Samsung phones and differences when viewed on the web).

Comment: I need to add some more emojis too so this link is really helpful 